RAG can be done using langchain, Now CohereForAI's Command R +, provides similar functionality, how it is is better than langchain's implementation?
How langchain's RAG implementation is different from the CohereforAI(Command R+) RAG functionality and what edge does it provide over the langchain RAG implementation.
I tried both of them, But I am unable to understand how they differ from each other.

Yeah better in what metric? How to compute that?
